# trans And Translate Not Working On Any Pages

Tags: django, django-i18n

Im copying Django Templates straight from Git and pasting them into overridden templates in my project (so there are no syntax errors), but I get this error message on every page that uses translate or trans:

```
Invalid block tag on line 38: 'translate', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

My settings file is unchanged from when I began the project and as I said, im copying the code straight from the git repository. Im guessing the problem is in my settings.py file. Ive Googled and tried everything i can find but cant seem to find the problem.

Can anybody please help shed some light on what the issue might be?

Thank you.

PS I know im giving little code, but I cant think of how to offer more code without just pasting my whole settings.py file :s

Comment: did you loaded the i18n at the top of your template? `{% load i18n %}` and then `{% trans "Your string to be translated" %}`, `translate` as is is not a default template tag in django, it is `trans` or `blocktrans`as docs says https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag

Comment: Oh thank you... All I had to do was change 'translate' to 'trans'.. The part thats got me confused (and why I never thought to do that) is because the code came straight from the Django Git repository : https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html . Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code) (and thanks to Gabriel for mentioning in the comments) you need to add `{% load i18n %}` toward the top of your template for being able to use `translate` and `blocktranslate` tags.

In Django 3.1 `trans` and `blocktrans` tags was renamed to `translate` and `blocktranslate` tags accordingly by keeping backwards compatibility.